# Setup Node with UWS and SSL

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm looking for documentation or an example on how to properly configure UWS with WWS/SSL. Currently I'm simply doing:

```
this.server = new WebSocket.Server({
   port: this.config.port,
   verifyClient: this.authenticate.bind(this)
});
```

Which obviously just binds a basic socket. Do I need to initialize a separate https with the settings and plug it into the UWS options?

If so does that still leverage the UWS internals with SSL? I have no idea how the internalized structure looks so just curious.

Last question, can I use DH as an additional cipher? Would I have the ability to do something similar to setting up an Express server?

```
this.api = express.createServer({
  key: config.certs.key,
  cert: config.certs.cert,
  dhparam: config.certs.dh,
  secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2
});
this.api.use(helmet.hsts({
  maxAge: 31536000000,
  includeSubdomains: true,
  force: true
}));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to initialize a separate https with the settings and plug it into the UWS options?

Yes.

> If so does that still leverage the UWS internals with SSL? I have no idea how the internalized structure looks so just curious.

Some of it. [Specifying the https server](https://github.com/uNetworking/bindings/blob/c90322386578c5c4de8e833c10ef9383438920a5/nodejs/examples/ssl.js#L10-L15), means you [won't use the built-in http server](https://github.com/uNetworking/bindings/blob/c90322386578c5c4de8e833c10ef9383438920a5/nodejs/src/uws.js#L384-L387).

> Last question, can I use DH as an additional cipher? Would I have the ability to do something similar to setting up an Express server?

Sure. `express.createServer` (or [`https.createServer`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) for that matter) accepts options from [`tls.createSecureContext`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options), which includes `dhparam`.